# Get the Firefox "save as" dialog to stop guessing where I want to save my file

Tags: linux, firefox, gnome

I download a lot of files into different folders. But the Firefox "save as" dialog is too smart for its own good. It tries to guess which folder I want to save files in (I assume by what website it's from), not where I last saved a file. So when I want to download something, the dialog jumps off to somewhere else in the filesystem, (based on some file I downloaded a long time ago,) so I have to navigate back to the folder I was downloading things into. This slows me down tremendously. It also causes me to accidentally save files in the wrong folders.

Is there a way to get the dialog to always set the default folder to the last folder I saved a file in, like how it works in Chromium?

Comment: I use DIrectFolder by CodeSector to quickly go to different folders.  That bypasses this issue.... when it works.  It seems that newer software has started interfering with it, and it hasn't gotten an update in many years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is controlled by the [browser.download.lastDir.savePerSite](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/Preference_reference/browser.download.lastDir.savePerSite) preferences.

As of Firefox 55 this preference does not appear by default in about:config, you have to add it (right click / New / Boolean)